# Why don't Scalar::Util and Test::Most play well together?

Tags: perl

Take this simple test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Test::Most;
use Scalar::Util qw( reftype );

ok( 1, 'foo' );

done_testing();
```

Running this test gives me the following output:

Prototype mismatch: sub main::reftype: none vs ($) at /Users/olaf/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.2/lib/site_perl/5.16.2/Exporter.pm line 66.

There are 2 ways I can get rid of this warning.

- I can use Test::More rather than Test::Most
- I can use Test::Most but not explicitly import reftype

I'm ok with calling Scalar::Util::reftype (or even using another module), but I'm looking for a little help in debugging this issue so that I can file the appropriate bug report, since I'm not sure as to where the root cause of the warning lies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `Test::Most` and `Scalar::Util` define functions called `reftype`, and the way you are calling `use` causes both modules to try to export their `reftype` functions to the calling package. Sometimes this will trigger a `Subroutine ... redefined` warning, but in this case `Scalar::Util::reftype` wants to define itself with a prototype, so the conflict is a more serious error.

Some options other than calling `Scalar::Util::reftype($ref)`:

One. to define and use a different alias for `Scalar::Util::reftype`

```
     use Scalar::Util ();
     BEGIN { *su_reftype = *Scalar::Util::reftype; }
     print "reftype is ", su_reftype($ref), " ...";
```

Two. Remove `reftype` from the symbol table before loading `Scalar::Util`:

```
    use Test::Most;
    BEGIN { *{reftype} = '' }
    use Scalar::Util 'reftype';
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Using your second option I got "Ambiguous use of *{reftype} resolved to *reftype". Changing that to BEGIN { *reftype = '' } did the trick. I can't actually see where Test::Most is exporting reftype, but this answers my immediate question.

Comment: As a footnote to this, perl -MDevel::Peek -MTest::Most -e'Dump(\&reftype)' tells me that the culprit is Test::Deep

Comment: It's exported from `Test::Deep`, which dynamically creates a series of constructor methods from the keys of `%Test::Deep::constructors` (which includes `RefType`).

Comment: You surely want to import it at compile time as always, so I adjusted the node.